# Non Square Unitary Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

In numerous sources online, I have found three claims

- Unitary matrices follow $U^* = U^{-1}$, where $^*$ is the conjugate transpose
- Unitary matrices can be non-square, as long as all columns and rows are orthonormal
- Non-square matrices do not have inverses

These statements seem to form a contradiction, though I feel like it has something to do with complex numbers. Can anybody help clarify the statements above, and provide an example of a non-square unitary matrix?

**Correction**

After copious amounts of google searching, I forgot that the second statement was an assumption I made. I was under the impression that if non-square matrices have SVDs, then the left-singular-matrix and right-singular-matrix had to be non-square. I just realized that in those cases, they are actually square, and it is the diagonal matrix that is non-square. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first statement is certainly true since it is a possible definition of unitary matrices. In my opinion, it is not possible to define non-square unitary matrices because how would you define a unity matrix in the space $L(m,n)$, i.e. the space of linear maps from a $m$-dimensional to a $n$-dimensional vector space? Where did you get that claim from?

Comment: oh sorry nevermind I figured it out. I was under the impression that if nonsquare matrices have SVDs, then the left-singular-matrix and right-singular-matrix had to be nonsquare. I just realized that in those cases, the diagonal matrix had to be nonsquare. My bad

Comment: Is there a name for non square matrices which obey $ {X}^{T} X = I $?

Comment: @Royi semi-unitary

Comment: Yep. In Wikipedia it is [Semi Orthogonal Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix).